# Joining 3 tables in SQL showing all 3 tables

Tags: sql, join, mysql-workbench

I am a basic user of SQL but need to join 3 tables together to sow a) sales b) returns and c) profit

I currently have the following code

```
select * from (
select  SUM(Return_Amount) , 'Return' as type, monthname(Return_Date) as month_
from returns
group by month_
union 

select  SUM(Order_Total_Cost) , 'Sales' as type, monthname(Order_Date) as month_
from sales
group by month_

union 
select SUM(profit) as profit_  , 'Profit' as type, month_
from(
select sell_price-cost_price as profit , monthname(order_date) month_
from sales
join order_item
on order_item.order_No = sales.order_No 
join returns 
on returns.order_no = sales.order_No 
join supplier
on supplier.Product_ID = order_item.Product_ID
) B group by month_
) A order by month_;
```

This is showing as below:

```
387 Return  August
182 Sales   August
867 Profit  August
733 Return  July
109 Sales   July
646 Profit  July
596 Return  June
```

I want it to show with Return, Sales & Profit as separate columns instead of all types listed in one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not join them?

```
SELECT x.month_
     , x.returns_
     , y.sales_
     , z.profit_
FROM
  (SELECT SUM(Return_Amount) AS returns_
        , monthname(Return_Date) AS month_
   FROM RETURNS
   GROUP BY month_) x
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT SUM(Order_Total_Cost) AS sales_
        , monthname(Order_Date) AS month_
   FROM sales
   GROUP BY month_) y ON x.month_ = y.month_
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT SUM(profit) AS profit_
        , month_
   FROM
     (SELECT sell_price-cost_price AS profit
           , monthname(order_date) month_
      FROM sales
      INNER JOIN order_item ON order_item.order_No = sales.order_No
      INNER JOIN RETURNS ON returns.order_no = sales.order_No
      INNER JOIN supplier ON supplier.Product_ID = order_item.Product_ID) B
   GROUP BY month_) z ON x.month_ = z.month_
```

Answer (score 0):

You could turn the three `union`ed queries to subqueries and join them. This assumes that each subquery always produces one record per month.

Also: you probably want to join and month *and year*, in case your data spans over multiple years (which eventually happens in any live dataset). I would also recommend using numeric years and month (as returned by `year()` and `month()`), which would produce more efficient joins than month names.

```
select 
    r.month_name,
    r.total_return_amount,
    s.total_sales,
    p.total_profit
from 
    (
        select 
            year(return_date) yr,
            month(return_date) mh,
            monthname(return_date) month_name
            sum(return_amount) total_return_amount, 
        from returns
        group by 
            year(return_date), 
            month(return_date),
            monthname(return_date)
    ) r
    inner join (
        select 
            year(order_date) yr,
            month(order_date) mh,
            sum(order_total_cost) total_sales
        from sales
        group by
            year(order_date),
            month(order_date)
    ) s on s.yr = r.yr and s.mh = r.mh
    inner join (
        select 
            year(order_date) yr,
            month(order_date) mh,
            sum(sell_price - cost_price) as total_profit , 
        from sales
        inner join order_item on order_item.order_no = sales.order_no 
        inner join returns on returns.order_no = sales.order_no 
        inner join supplier on supplier.product_id = order_item.product_id
        group by
            year(order_date),
            month(order_date)
    ) p on p.yr = r.yr and p.mh = r.mh
```